# Running Tkinter alongside a Textual Game?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

How do I allow for graphics to be updated from textual input on IDLE's command line? If I have something like:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
can = Canvas(root, height=500, width=100)
can.pack()
mainloop()

x = input("what is a number? ")
print x
```

The window will appear, but the prompt on the command line won't. Any ideas on how I could allow for this?

Comment: You need to completely rethink how you do input once you throw in an event loop.

Comment: try putting the lines of code under the mainloop above it :)

Comment: The question is, why do you want the input to come from the commandline when you're effectively generating a GUI?  Typically, you would probably want to create a Toplevel window which prompts the user for a number, has them enter it in an Entry field and then returns that value back to your program ...  Of course you can always define a callback which prompts for a number too, but you'll freeze your GUI until the user puts in a number...

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for debugging or one shot config/input, you could pass it as a command line parameter to your program, or put the prompt code anywhere before the mainloop() call.  If on the other hand it's ongoing input to the game, you should add a text input field and probably a button to your main form so the user can input data and press the button to indicate when they're done typing and have an event handler tied to the button process the contents of the input field.

If none of the above made much sense, take a look at the site [TkDocs](http://www.tkdocs.com/index.html) which has lots of useful info about Tk, including code samples of how to make all the calls in Python (among other languages).

Answer (score 0):

I would  suggest just using tkinter's widgets.

```
import Tkinter as tk

def numEntered(*args):
    print x.get()
    x.set('')
    return

root = tk.Tk()
can = tk.Canvas(root, height=500, width=100)
can.pack()

inputFrame=tk.LabelFrame(root, text="What is a number?")
inputFrame.pack()

x=tk.StringVar()
inputEntry=tk.Entry(inputFrame,textvariable=x)
inputEntry.pack()

inputEntry.bind('<Return>',numEntered)

tk.mainloop()
```

Notice several items:
1) I put the text entry in a label frame which helps when you are using the pack geometry manager. 2) I used the bind method to execute the function when the user inputs a number and hits the enter (return) key. 3) the function prints the number and then clears the variable.

I hope this helps!